# Rails omniauth-saml gem is not signing the SAMLRequest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, saml

Apologies in advance for any incorrect terminology in this post. We are not SAML experts and have been following various gem README's and forum/blog posts to get as far as we have in our set up.

We need to create a SAML integration with an IDP that is requiring a signed 'handshake' before allowing our application to pass to their login page. We have set up SAML with the Rails omniauth-saml gem (https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-saml) and have successfully tested integration with Okta. However, the IDP we are trying to integrate with is not accepting our AuthnRequest. Based on their logs, we believe that this has to do with our SAMLRequest not being signed correctly. The omniauth-saml documentation does not provide any information about signing requests, but we were able to find information in the OneLogin ruby-saml gem which the omniauth-saml gem builds off of (https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml). We have set the signing services mentioned in onelogin/ruby-saml all to true and added signature method and digest methods, but our SAMLRequest still doesn't seem to be signed correctly. 
This is our settings information:

```
# we set security
  security = {authn_requests_signed: true, embed_sign: true, metadata_signed: true, soft: false, signature_method: XMLSecurity::Document::RSA_SHA1, digest_method: XMLSecurity::Document::SHA1}

  idp_metadata.merge(

    certificate: EXAMPLE_PUBLIC_CERT,
    private_key: EXAMPLE_PRIVATE_CERT,
    # we're using the environment variable here because each deploy of
    # our app has a different domain name 
    issuer: "https://" + ENV['MAIL_HOST'] + "/users/auth/saml/metadata",
    assertion_consumer_service_url: "https://" + ENV['MAIL_HOST'] + "/users/auth/saml/callback",
    assertion_consumer_service_binding: "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST",
    # these attributes are set elsewhere
    request_attributes: attributes,
    security: security
  )
```

We are using the omniauth-saml generated path for redirecting to the IDP with the SAMLRequest GET param: user_saml_omniauth_authorize_path

We couldn't find any information about additional parameters that should be passed to the authorize_path to force signing or anything along those lines.

It is our understanding that if our SAMLRequest was being signed correctly, the consumer of the SAMLRequest would need the 509Certificate information from our metadata xml to decode it, but we are able to decode the SAMLRequest in the generic OneLogin decoder without additional information.

Any help with forcing the Authn signing of our SAMLRequest would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to create **Google SAML SSO** custom app integration for my Rails website. I am using** omniauth-saml** gem. However, I am really confused with "**ACS URL**" and "**Entity ID**" that needs to be set under "**Service Provider Details**" during google saml idp setup. I have a few questions as follows: any guidance is really appreciated:

Comment: 1. What should be the **ACS URL**? My understanding: It should be the URL at which the SAML assertion should be received sent by Google. If that is correct, what is the use of **:assertion_consumer_service_url**, which can be set in rails app as: `Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do provider :saml, :assertion_consumer_service_url => "acs url here!!" # my-rails-app.com/sso/saml_asertion_handler ... end` 

**Will this overwrite the ACS URL set in the google portal and send response to the one specified in the Omniauth config?**

Comment: what should be the **Entity ID**? My understanding: It should be the url of my rails app(`my-rails-app.com`). However, I found a few places where saml metadata url is specified(`my-rails-app.com/auth/saml/metadata`).

Comment: 3. What should be the **:issuer** in OmniAuth::Builder in rails config? - Just like **Entity Id**, I found it be the 'application name'(my-rails-app.com) as well as the path to the metadata (my-rails-app.com/auth/saml/metadata).